# How can I merge two pdfs in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel-8, tcpdf

I have one dynamically generated pdf using tcpdf library. and after that user will upload another pdf and while user download the form as pdf it should have the both pdfs in one pdf. For that I need to merge those pdfs.
If anyone can help please reply !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/Webklex/laravel-pdfmerger

I used this and it works fine but in my case Firstly T need save dynamically generated pdf at some location and then pass the path to the pdfmerger

But at last it works great!!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

It's not a Laravel thing, we have tools for that in PHP, for example the [libmergepdf](https://github.com/hanneskod/libmergepdf) library which is updated for PHP 8 and does get the job done quite easily.

Also, if u want it to be a Laravel like solution you can create a service provider yourself or maybe easier create a MergePdfService class and write the PDF merging code there then call it from your controllers or whatever with two file paths or streams.